# http error due to image that not belong in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, https, malware

My wordpress site is https. But the pricing page  does not come in `https`.

**It gives the error of images which is of http:**

[image]

Now this folder **`uploads/fbrfg`** **have not been created by me**..it should be a **`malware`**..but when I deleted that folder, the image file still shows in http error. How should I remove that image files and that folder?

I've installed shield security plugin to delete unnecessary files too, but it didn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think that the `uploads/fbrfg` folder is 'malware'? Does it contain any webshells or other suspicious files? If you do a google search for 'uploads/fbrfg' you'll see hundreds of sites that have this folder in their wp-content directory. My guess is that it is automatically created by some plugin, so when you delete the folder the plugin creates it again. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: okay but it gives http, how should I make it https? @t.m.adam

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that either. Your browser issues a warning because data is not encrypted over http, but in this case it's not that important because they're just internal links to images. If you think it's important, then just edit the links.